# Setting up GTK for C in vs code windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gtk

Im trying to set up vs code to work with gtk, I'm programming in c, I followed the instruction on how to install [**gtk**](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) using **msys64**, then I tried to run an [hello world](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) example from their page, but vs code seem to have problems finding the gtk header files.

**error:** `gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory`

I beleive as well that gtk is installed as i run the command `kg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`

**Output:**  -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gtk-4.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pango-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/lzo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pixman-1 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/graphene-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/graphene-1.0/include -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib -lgtk-4 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgraphene-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

c_cpp_properties:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Gtk_dev",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/**",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gtk-4.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/graphene-1.0/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false,
                "path": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations?

Comment: well my folder already had c_cpp_properties , i even tried to tweak it to the ones I saw who were trying to get gtk working

Comment: my apologies, I've included it